# Evaluation of integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itx} \frac{1- e^{-\frac 1 2 t^2}}{\frac 1 2 t^2} \text d t$ / specific characteristic Function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

I want to calculate the value of
$$I(x) :=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itx} \frac{1- e^{-\frac 1 2 t^2}}{\frac 1 2 t^2} \text d t$$
where $x\in \Bbb R$. Of course we can write
$$I(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos (tx) \frac{1- e^{-\frac 1 2 t^2}}{\frac 1 2 t^2} \text d t + i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin (tx) \frac{1- e^{-\frac 1 2 t^2}}{\frac 1 2 t^2} \text d t$$
But I have no approach to this integrals.

OR

Does someone know a distribution with characteristic function $\frac{1- e^{-\frac 1 2 t^2}}{\frac 1 2 t^2} $ ?

Comment: $\displaystyle\texttt{Mathematica} \implies 2 \pi  \left| x\right|  \left(\frac{\text{erf} \left| x\right| }{\sqrt{2}}-1\right)+2 \sqrt{2 \pi } e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x>0$,
\begin{align}
I(x)&=\int_0^1\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{itx-yt^2/2}\,dt\,dy
\\ &=\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{y}}e^{-x^2/2y}\,dy &&\color{gray}{\text{[known inner integral]}}
\\ &=2x\sqrt{2\pi}\int_x^\infty\frac{e^{-z^2/2}}{z^2}\,dz &&\color{gray}{\text{[substitution $y=x^2/z^2$]}}
\\ &=2\sqrt{2\pi}\left(e^{-x^2/2}-x\int_x^\infty e^{-z^2/2}\,dz\right) &&\color{gray}{\text{[integration by parts]}}
\\ &=2\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-x^2/2}-2\pi x\operatorname{erfc}(x/\sqrt{2}).
\end{align}

Comment: I think it should be $2\sqrt{2\pi}e^{-x^2/2}-2\pi \vert x\vert \operatorname{erfc}(x/\sqrt{2})$ ($I(x)$ should be symmetric and the substitution is $z = \frac{\vert x \vert}{\sqrt{y}}$). Thank you very much. And in particular thanks for not giving any more argument to the known inner integral. This is the one of the wonderful parts of the solution and thus I had the chance to find this by myself.